# SQL Server Agent is not visible in SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have been monitoring the server for past 4 days but i am not able to see agent on SSms but the agent service is in running mode and the server is of standard edition

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the wrong version of SSMS being installed.

If you're absolutely sure you have the correct version of SQL server installed on your server, which you can test by opening services.msc and checking if the SQL Server Agent is present.
[image: SQL Server Agent]

then make sure you have the correct version of SSMS installed on your workstation. You can follow the steps explained in this [MSDN reply about SSMS versions and SQL server Agent](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fa17e59a-b676-4e87-b71b-ca6316250467/sql-server-agent-not-appearing-in-management-studio?forum=sqldatabaseengine).

Summary:

- You don't have SSMS Express installed
- You have the correct permissions on the server
- You have the complete, and not basic, version of SSMS installed